# Create menu / submenu from category subcategory and posts

Tags: categories, menus, navigation, walker

I have a custom menu made up of pages and categories and I am trying to output the category and subcategories as well as the last 4 posts from each category/ subcategory.

In trying to use a walker class I borrowed from an example class

```
    function walk( $elements, $max_depth) {

    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
    $output = '';

    if ($max_depth < -1) //invalid parameter
        return $output;

    if (empty($elements)) //nothing to walk
        return $output;

    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
    $parent_field = $this->db_fields['parent'];

    // flat display
    if ( -1 == $max_depth ) {
        $empty_array = array();
        foreach ( $elements as $e )
            $this->display_element( $e, $empty_array, 1, 0, $args, $output );
        return $output;
    }

    /*
     * need to display in hierarchical order
     * separate elements into two buckets: top level and children elements
     * children_elements is two dimensional array, eg.
     * children_elements[10][] contains all sub-elements whose parent is 10.
     */
    $top_level_elements = array();
    $children_elements  = array();
    foreach ( $elements as $e) {
        if ( 0 == $e->$parent_field )
        {
            $top_level_elements[] = $e;
            $child_posts = array();
            if($e->object == 'category')
            {
              $child_cats = blankslate_get_menu_categories($e->object_id); // custom function to get categories of category
              $child_posts = blankslate_get_menu_posts($e->object_id, 'post', 4, true); // custom function to get posts of category
              if(!empty($child_cats))
              {
                $child_posts = array_merge($child_cats, $child_posts);
                $output = $this->walk($child_cats, 0);
              }
            } else $child_posts = blankslate_get_menu_posts($e->object_id, $e->object);

                if(!empty($child_posts)) $e->classes[] = "menu-item-has-children";
            foreach ( $child_posts as $child ) {
                $child = wp_setup_nav_menu_item($child);
                $child->post_type = 'nav_menu_item';
                $child->menu_item_parent = $e->$id_field;
                $child->ID = $e->$id_field.$child->ID;
                $children_elements[ $e->$id_field ][] = $child;
                $children_elements_classes[] = $child;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $children_elements[ $e->$parent_field ][] = $e;
        }
    }

    /*
     * when none of the elements is top level
     * assume the first one must be root of the sub elements
     */
    if ( empty($top_level_elements) ) {

        $first = array_slice( $elements, 0, 1 );
        $root = $first[0];

        $top_level_elements = array();
        $children_elements  = array();
        foreach ( $elements as $e) {
          if ( $root->$parent_field == $e->$parent_field )
          {
              $top_level_elements[] = $e;
              if($e->object == 'category')
               {
                 $child_cats = blankslate_get_menu_categories($e->object_id);
                 $child_posts = blankslate_get_menu_posts($e->object_id, 'post', 4, true);
                 if(!empty($child_cats))
                 {
                   $child_posts = array_merge($child_cats, $child_posts);
                 }


               } else $child_posts = blankslate_get_menu_posts($e->object_id, $e->object);
              if(!empty($child_posts)) $e->classes[] = 'menu-item-has-children';
              foreach ( $child_posts as $child ) {
                  $child = wp_setup_nav_menu_item($child);
                  $child->post_type = 'nav_menu_item';
                  $child->menu_item_parent = $e->$id_field;
                  $child->ID = $e->$id_field.$child->ID;
                  $children_elements[ $e->$id_field ][] = $child;
                  $children_elements_classes[] = $child;
              }
          }
          else
          {
              $children_elements[ $e->$parent_field ][] = $e;
          }
        }
    }

    //assing the classes to our dynamically populated posts
    if ( isset($children_elements_classes) )
        _wp_menu_item_classes_by_context($children_elements_classes);

    foreach ( $top_level_elements as $e )
        $this->display_element( $e, $children_elements, $max_depth, 0, $args, $output );

    /*
     * if we are displaying all levels, and remaining children_elements is not empty,
     * then we got orphans, which should be displayed regardless
     */
    if ( ( $max_depth == 0 ) && count( $children_elements ) > 0 ) {
        $empty_array = array();
        foreach ( $children_elements as $orphans )
            foreach( $orphans as $op )
                $this->display_element( $op, $empty_array, 1, 0, $args, $output );
     }

     return $output;
}
```

However I'm not sure how to transverse through the fetched categories to get the sub categories and posts in depth. Can anyone advise me on what steps I can take for this walk class to work?